# What exactly a file system like EXT4/XFS contains on a disk partition in Linux apart from data blocks?

Tags: linux

At low level, what happens when we format a newly created disk using mkfs?

Comment: Hello @Rajan Jha, welcome to the Stack Overflow community. To help you find resolution to problems you're having please first review the [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please understand that the purpose of the community isn't to complete research for the author of a post. Rather, the community is here to help once you've researched the surrounding documentation and put something into practice, then you'll find the community will chip in with us in finding resolution. Please research this and return with an actual question.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for system configuration commands, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

mkfs formats the partition you selected and you can format with the filessytem you choose
Ex: mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sda1

You can also use

mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1